# Dynamics CRM 2011 Windows Service Error

Tags: windows-services, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a Windows service that connects to Dynamics CRM to perform a periodic data load.

This error is occurring:
The authentication endpoint Username was not found on the configured Secure Token Service!

The service was working previously, but the code has been changing and possible something has changed on the CRM server or the server running the Windows service.

The application runs if started as a console application from the same machine that it is failing on as a Windows service.

The application runs on my dev machine as a service and as a console application.

```c#
public class CRMSync
{
    /* There are more fields and methods that are not pertinent */
    /* Called by CRMAUX.OnStart when it is time to start the service */
    public async void Start()
    {
        this.Test();
        var freq = 0;
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
        var parse = int.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Frequency"], out freq);
        await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay((parse) ? freq * 1000 * 60 : 15000 * 60); // 15 minutes default or user defined
        Start();
    }
    /* Do something to test */
    private void Test()
    {
        Connect(); // Connect to CRM and instantiate service and linq (the service context)
        Log(linq.sbuys_scriptsSet.FirstOrDefault().sbuys_Number); // Write to the Event Viewer
        service.Dispose(); // Dispose the OrganizationServiceProxy
    }
}
```

EDIT

This is the Connect Method

```c#
    /* Tries to connect to CRM and return false if failure - credentials arguments */
    private bool Connect(string username, string password, string uri)
    {
        try
        {
            var cred = new ClientCredentials();
            cred.UserName.UserName = username;
            cred.UserName.Password = password;
            service = new OrganizationServiceProxy(new Uri(uri), null, cred, null);
            service.EnableProxyTypes(); // this has to happen to allow LINQ early bound queries
            linq = new Context(service);
            var who = new Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages.WhoAmIRequest(); // used to test the connection
            var whoResponse = (Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages.WhoAmIResponse)service.Execute(who); // this fails if not connected       
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log(e.Message);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: 1. you need to post your `Connect()` method. 2. if the same code works correctly when run from command-line, and not when run as a service, i would look into what user is configured to run the service; maybe that user doesn't have permissions...

Comment: The same CRM user is configured for the service as for the console application; I have posted the connected method. When the service runs from another server there is no problem. Could it be that the Windows user running the service does not have access to the certificate store?